# I need some help centering and getting text and images inline (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I need to get the text and the image below in the same line, centered. Im using the data-role="header" function in jquery, but cant seem to get everything in one line and centered. The CSS is the Jquery Standard

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>jQuery</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/scavenger-hunt.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="Publish/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
        <body> 

<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Scavenger</h1><img src="images/logosh.png" alt="logo" width="50" height="50" align="absmiddle"><h1>Hunt</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to have Scavenger<img>Hunt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your h1's first then your image last in the html and css should be like this

```
 #home > div h1:first-child {float:left}
#home > div h1 {float:right}
img {display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
```

here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tbd5f/1/

Comment: I *think* the OP wants the image and text in a single line (i.e. both `display: inline`, but centered within the header.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend against from breaking up the header into two separate `<h1>` elements, because that's unnecessary and not too correct :P

Try using this HTML code:

```
<h1>
    Scavenger
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="logo" width="50" height="50" align="absmiddle">
    Hunt
</h1>
```

And this CSS:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```